# Display of Language options should in series as displayed in list though user selects deselects random options?

Tags: java, alphabetical-sort

please can anybody help me to overcome this.problem. Problem statement is :

I wrote some code for displaying languages  of user selection from web page due to some check box's.Suppose user select two check box's for German and Urdu then I need to show on web page German,Urdu.Then after user again select another language option like Arabic then I need to show on web page like Arabic,German,Urdu.

Thanks advanced.

```
   knownLanguages ="German,Urdu,Arabic";  
   String userLanguages[] = knownLanguages.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < userLanguages.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0)
        knownLanguages1 += userLanguages[i];
      else
        knownLanguages1 += " , " + userLanguages[i];
    }
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(knownLanguages1.split(" , ")));
    Collections.sort(list, ALPHABETICAL_ORDER);
    return knownLanguages1;
  }

  private static Comparator<String> ALPHABETICAL_ORDER = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
      int res = String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(str1, str2);
      if (res == 0) {
        res = str1.compareTo(str2);
      }
      return res;
    }
  };
```

But this code don't give desired output.Please help me.

Comment: Well it is just a piece of code... not complete... Idk but for example it looks like it can not work because you are returning knownLanguages1 what should be exactly same as knownLanguages :D

Comment: But after changing as list and do some process for sorting then also it's not give proper sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a custom comparator since all you're doing is `alphabetical sorting`.

Following code should work for you:

```
String knownLanguages ="German,Urdu,Arabic";
// get a list of languages from above string using String#split
List<String> langList = Arrays.asList(knownLanguages.split(","));
// sort the resulting list
Collections.sort(langList);
// print it
System.out.println(langList);
// OUTPUT: [Arabic, German, Urdu]
```

Comment: Sir it's working perfectly as per my requirement.Please guide me how to give the votes.Thank you so much sir.

Comment: You're welcome. Once you have 15 reps or more you can upvote any question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private static Comparator<String> ALPHABETICAL_ORDER = new Comparator<String>() {
         public int compare(String str1, String str2) {         
             return  str1.compareToIgnoreCase(str2);;
         }      
   };
```

Comment: No it's compile.But not give proper solution.

Comment: Sorry this code is not working for me it's also give random sorting order on web page.